# How to add loading screen to cover up the sign in page showing at the launch of the app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In the code below ,if the user is already signed in and the app is launched, it shows the SignIn() page for a second and then goes to the HomeScreen(). How can the user be brought directly to the HomeScreen() without showing the SignIn() page if the user is already signed in?
I'm trying to show the loading screen for time when the auth status of the user is verified but it still shows the SignIn() screen for a second or less.

```
class Wrapper extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _WrapperState createState() => _WrapperState();
    }

    class _WrapperState extends State<Wrapper> {
      bool loading = true;

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final user = Provider.of<User>(context);

        //return either HomeScreen or SignIn widget.

        if (user != null) {
           setState ((){
              loading = false;
           });

          return loading ? Loading() : HomeScreen();
        } else {
          return SignIn();
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Code should be like

```
  if(loginStatus != null) { // This you must get from somewhere
     SignIn(); 
   }
   else if(user == null) {
       Loading(); 
    } else {
       HomeScreen(); 
    }
```

I think you must have the status of device login is performed or not, based on that add another condition and show SignIn screen.

Comment: Whenever I return HomeScreen, its going to check for user != null, and that is done on the SignIn page. So it shows the SignIn for some milliseconds..and this is what i want to cover behind the loading screen..

Comment: This should be done at the main widget where you have to decide among these three widgets which one to show, here you can't able to solve the issue.

Comment: My main.dart file points to this widget..this widget decides which screen to show.. So first it checks if the user==null then it shows screen depending on that information. Do you mean that i should make changes in the main.dart?

Comment: yes, your main.dart file should decide, you can also use FutureBuilder for your purpose.